# BaseAdapter inside Fragment not updating the content

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, firebase, baseadapter

I'm working with Firebase and I have a ListView inside a Fragment. In the first load and changes on Firebase content, everything works fine. But, after replace the Fragment (to provide search feature on other Fragment) and revert the FragmentTransaction the BaseAdapter doesn't update correctly (@android:id/empty is shown).

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content, mCategoriesPopularFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
    /** Reverting FragmentTransaction */
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
    /** Replacing by "search" Fragment */
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content, mCategoriesFragment)
            .addToBackStack("CategoriesFragment")
            .commit();
    return true;
}
```

**CategoriesPopularFragment.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories_popular, container, false);

    ...

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mLoadingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mFirebaseRef.orderByChild("name").addValueEventListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mFirebaseRef.removeEventListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    List<Category> allItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Category c = Category.populateFromFirebase(d);
        if (c.isPopular()) {
            allItems.add(c);
        }
    }

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new CategoryPopularAdapter(getContext(), allItems);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.updateItems(allItems);
    }

    mLoadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

**CategoryPopularAdapter.java**

```
public CategoryPopularAdapter(Context context, List<Category> items) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mItems = new ArrayList<>(items);
}

public void updateItems(List<Category> items) {
    mItems.clear();
    mItems.addAll(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**fragment_categories_popular.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="br.com.jzone.comprebem.fragment.CategoriesPopularFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loading_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_category" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_default_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/activity_main_no_category_found_message"
        android:textColor="@color/gray" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is this problem related to FragmentTransaction? I hope someone helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Why use BaseAdapter over ArrayAdapter? (not that that should fix the problem, just curious)

Comment: No specific reason @cricket_007, I just think it easier to work.

Comment: Did you trace what path the code takes in `onDataChanged` for 'categoriesPopularFragment' when popping backstack? I'm curious to know if it creates a new adapter or updates an existing.  Also, I don't see what 'CategoryPopularAdapter' is implementing so safe to assume it's `BaseAdapter`?